# Determining the Type for a generic method parameter at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Given the a class with the following structure. I am trying to determine the type of the parameter T assigned by the caller of the generic method.

```
public class MyClass{

    public <T> Boolean IsSupportable() {

        Class typeOfT; // Need to determine Class for generic parameter T

        // Business Logic goes here 

        return true; 
    }
}
```

In C# I would use "default(T)" or "typeof(T)" but I am trying to do this in Java. Does anyone know how/if I can do this? I don't really need an instance, I just need the Class definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. What you could do is make the method signature like this:

```
public boolean isSupportable(Class<?> type)
```

Then you can use the given class to check the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, generics aren't available at runtime. If you had an instance of T, you could always check if `T object` was an instance of a specific class with `instanceof`.

This is due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

An other way is to use the `Class` class as a parameter (see @ColinD's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850588/determining-the-type-for-a-generic-method-parameter-at-runtime/3850612#3850612))