# Generics type inference in Java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining the Type for a generic method parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850588/determining-the-type-for-a-generic-method-parameter-at-runtime)
>   [Generics in static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213472/generics-in-static-methods)

The code below fails at runtime with `cannot select from a type variable`. Is there any way of doing this without having to pass the type as a parameter (`Class<E[]> type`)?

```
public static <E extends Deal> E[] parseDealsFromJSON(String body) {
    parser.fromJson(body, E[].class); // fails here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubDeal[] deals = parseDealsFromJSON("");
}
```

Comment: The short answer; No. Follows the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213472/generics-in-static-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem is that the right hand size of `=` has no idea what type you want on the left hand side. i.e. java doesn't do this kind of type inference.

A method doesn't know what type you need a return type to be. (I have seen exceptions at runtime with MethodHandles and I suspect that Java 8 or 9 might introduce these features)

e.g. very basic type inference for return types isn't done at runtime (or compile time)

```
public Double getValue() {
    return 5.0;
}

double d = m.getValue(); // not smart enough to avoid creating a `Double` here.
```

---

With Generics you have the added bonus of type erasure.  This mean `E[]` is actually `Deal[]` at runtime. Which Deal type you might have liked is lost.